# Why is a Swift String not an Array type

Tags: swift

This often asked question is always answered in the same way: it’s because the string’s character content is a set of Unicode objects having possibly different lengths.

Surely this is non-answer? A character array is an array of Unicode characters! A simple String extension can of course provide the convenience of accessing individual characters using the familiar indexing method.

So I am missing the point here. Assuming there is a sound reason, what is it?

I’m leaving this question up rather than deleting it as it may help others who, like me, didn’t think deeply enough about the point :(

Comment: You answered your own question. Arrays provide constant-time access to their elements, while UTF-8 Strings cannot (at least, not without a separate array that caches the indices).

Comment: Thank you. Of course it’s all to do with performance and of course memory. An array of Unicode characters as with any variable length object array must have an associated index array. Although for a constant type this could be done at compile time there would be a performance hit at run time for variables and for large character arrays a large memory hit. So yes I now see that  String has its place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it’s because the string’s character content is a set of Unicode objects having possibly different lengths

This is an insufficient answer, and you're right that it's not satisfying. What's missing here is that text handling is incredibly complicated, and the definition of *what a character is* can change between Unicode versions. For example, Unicode 12 redefined how extended grapheme clusters are treated so they could be arbitrarily long and matched by a well-defined regex.

Unicode rules are built into the Swift standard library, so the boundaries between characters can change at runtime depending on the contents of the string and which OS version you're running on; this gives a consistent handling of all strings on the platform for all Swift applications.

This does mean that any effort to split up a string of Unicode code points (scalars) into Swift `Character`s at compile-time could be incorrect: not only would the compiler need to learn about Unicode character rules, but those rules could be incorrect for the target OS (e.g., imagine compiling an application with the Swift 5.x compiler, but running the application on an OS with a Swift 5.y standard library — your indices could be wrong).

> A simple String extension can of course provide the convenience of accessing individual characters using the familiar indexing method.

This is true — an extension can do this, but the key is that it would be doing so at runtime, using the latest Unicode rules for splitting up the string into `Character`s, potentially at cost.

---

This is why `String` doesn't promise O(1) access to any individual character: because it needs to calculate where `Character`s start and end based on the rules it knows about at runtime. If you need O(1) access to individual characters, then you are indeed better off using `Array<Character>` based on the specific semantics you need.

Comment: I was about to delete my question Itai but I respect the effort you took in your answer. It is quite a deep question but considering the additional work required either at compile time or at run time  along with the need to store an index array providing O(1) access for Strings would be completely wasteful in many situations. Cheers!